# See parametric query sent to SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, parameterized

I am getting strange formatting errors while trying to update a row in SQLite through a C# wrapper. The issue is not in the wrapper, but in how I am passing the parameters to the parametric query.

Is there a way to see the SQL generated to send to the DB? I've looked up a lot but it seems it is not very common wanting this or at least, not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite's fundamental (C) interface you could use [sqlite3_trace](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/profile.html) (or `sqlite3_profile`, documented at the same URL) -- I'm not sure how those functions map to the C# interface though (indeed, SQLite might be specially compiled to omit them...).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the answer can be a little tricky..you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2789596/838405) for an explanation for SqlServer, I think that for Sqlite is the same